# Using Function inside a function not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting user IP through a function. And using another function to insert other data and the IP already stored in a function. But the problem is that the IP is not store in the database while other information is stored.

```
function getIp(){
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}

function cart(){
    if (isset($_GET['add_cart'])){
        global $con;
        $ip = getIp();
        $item_id = $_GET['add_cart'];


        $insert_pro = "INSERT INTO `ecommerce`.`cart` 
                      (p_id,ip_add) VALUES ($item_id,$ip)";
        $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_pro);
        echo"<script>window.open('self'.'index.php')</script>";
    }
}
```

When i run the whole query it stores nothing in the database but when i run the query without storing IP it works. There is a mistake in it but i am unable to configure it out. Kindly help me so that the whole query works.

Comment: Can you remove the echo and see if you get any errors?

Comment: @Jerodev i removed the echo but no errors there :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your database, the column `ip_add` is most likely set to `varchar`, and because of that you need to wrap your $ip in either `''` or `""` because it's a string.

So change your query to:

```
$insert_pro = "INSERT INTO `ecommerce`.`cart` 
                      (p_id,ip_add) VALUES ($item_id,'$ip')"
```

Comment: Hope you are not offended. You dont need to use concatenation if the string is double quoted

Comment: @RiggsFolly Not at all, it's just a personal preference as I find it easier to read with the concat :)

Comment: Really? What odd eyes you have granny!

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's most likely because of the color coding ^^

Comment: @Raja Well dont forget to accept this answer once the time limit is up.